# How to use entity autocomplete for "user" target_type with specific roles?

Tags: 8, users

I have created a form field with user autocomplete as below.

```
$form['user_list'] = [
      '#title' => ('Select User'),
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#target_type' => 'user',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#selection_settings' => [
        'include_anonymous' => FALSE,
        'roles' => ['sales'],
      ],
    ];
```

I used "#selection_settings" with roles specific, but this is not working.
I want to filter user with "sales" only.

Comment: Not a full answer because I haven't verified it works yet: Based on the plugin code, it looks like what you want is `['#selection_settings']['filter']['role'] = [...];`. The relevant code is in `Drupal\user\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\UserSelection`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selection settings array is passed to the plugin options,
 which in this case is `Drupal\user\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\UserSelection`.

In that class, you can see that the relevant array key is `$options['filter']['role']`, which is an array.

Therefore, the correct code here is:

```
$form['user_list'] = [
  '#title' => ('Select User'),
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'user',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#selection_settings' => [
    'include_anonymous' => FALSE,
    'filter' => [
      'role' => ['sales'],
    ],
  ],
];
```